# Confusion regarding reference to Latin in "Infinite Jest" book

Tags: meaning, book

In he book [Infinite Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Jest) there is a part where a character says

> It strikes me that EXIT signs would look to a native speaker of Latin like red-lit signs that say HE LEAVES.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5):

*Exit* is a Latin word meaning literally "he/she/it leaves". It comes from *ex* "out of, away from" + *it* "he/she/it goes", a form of *eō, īre*, "to go".

Comment: I believe this originated from stage directions: in fact,.when multiple characters leave, the direction changes to "exeunt."

Comment: (Exeunt = "they leave", multiple people)